# Express $\sin^8\theta+\sin^6\theta+\sin^4\theta+\sin^2\theta-2$ as a single term in terms of $\sin\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta = 1$, express $\sin^8\theta+\sin^6\theta+\sin^4\theta+\sin^2\theta-2$ as a single term in terms of $\sin\theta$.

We have \begin{align*}\sin^8\theta+\sin^6\theta+\sin^4\theta+\sin^2\theta &= \sin^6\theta(\sin^2\theta+1)+\sin^2\theta(\sin^2\theta+1)-2\\&=\sin^6\theta(2-\cos^2\theta)+\sin^2\theta(2-\cos^2\theta)-2,\end{align*} but I didn't see how to use that $\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta = 1$.

Comment: Hint: When $\cos^2 \theta + \cos \theta = 1$, you get automatically that $\cos \theta = \sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to try viewing the given assumption as $\cos\theta = 1-\cos^2\theta = \sin^2\theta$.

Comment: If we follow your method, the next step would be to reverse distribute that then note that  $\sin^6 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = (\sin^2 (\theta)) ^3 + \sin^2 \theta$  terms of  Note that, if there wasn't a simple trick here as noted in above comment, we could always just let $x = \cos \theta$ and solve the quadratic

Comment: Didn't mean to offend you, but are you sure the question wants to express it in terms of $\sin\theta$? It just makes more sense to express it in terms of $\cos\theta$ from the given assumption :O

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos^2 (t)+\cos (t)=1$$

$$\implies \sin^2 (t)=\cos(t)$$

$$\implies \sin^4 (t)=\cos^2 (t) $$

$$\implies \sin^4 (t)+\sin^2 (t)=1 $$

$$\implies \sin^8 (t)+\sin^6 (t)=\sin^4 (t) $$

$$\implies f(t)=\sin^4 (t)+1-2=$$
$$=\cos^2 (t)-1=-\sin^2 (t ) $$ which is your result .

Comment: Sorry, I had a misunderstanding of the question. It is why I erased my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta =1$ gives $(1-\sin^2\theta)+\cos\theta = 1$, so $\cos\theta = \sin^2\theta$. Therefore, we have \begin{align*}\sin^8\theta+\sin^6\theta+\sin^4\theta+\sin^2\theta-2 &= \cos^4\theta+\cos^3\theta+\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta-2\\&=(1-\sin^2\theta)^2+\cos\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)+\sin^2\theta-2\\&=(1-\sin^2\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)+\sin^2\theta-2\\&=-\sin^2\theta.\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$S=\sin^8x+\sin^6x+\sin^4x+\sin^2x-2=\cos^4x+\cos^3x+\cos^2x+\cos x-2$

Now $S=(\cos^2x+\cos x-1)\cos^2x+2(\cos^2x+\cos x-1)-\cos x=?$ as $\cos^2x+\cos x-1=0$