# Find the value of $2\cos ^6 x -2\cos ^4 x+\cos ^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

If $\tan x +\tan ^2x +\tan ^3 x =1$ then we have to find the value of  $2\cos ^6 x  -2\cos ^4 x+\cos ^2 x$ .

I am not getting any start can anybody provide me a hint .

Comment: Did you try squaring it and use identities?

Comment: @Koolman, What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The condition gives $$(\tan{x}+1)(\tan^2x+1)=2$$ or
$$2\cos^2x=\tan{x}+1.$$
Thus,
$$2\cos^6x-2\cos^4x+\cos^2x=\frac{(\tan{x}+1)^3}{4}-\frac{(\tan{x}+1)^2}{2}+\frac{\tan{x}+1}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{\tan^3x+\tan^2x+\tan{x}+1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Done!

Comment: Very neat solution. For the benefit of the OP, always remember your identities. $\tan^2 x$ can be easily converted to $\sec^2 x$, which is just the reciprocal of $\cos^2 x$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is how the problem came into being.

Ultimately we need to eliminate $\tan x$ using $$\tan^2x=\dfrac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}$$

Squaring $$2\cos^2x-1=\tan x$$
 & writing $\cos^2x=c$

$$\implies(2c-1)^2=\dfrac{1-c}c\iff2c^3-2c^2+c=\dfrac12$$

Comment: Your Question Reverse Engineering is appreciated! And upvoted. So appearently one source is $\,\cos 2x =\tan x\,$, *the task not to be solved*.

Comment: @Hanno, Not sure why this is called "". I this to be natural derivation without actually knowing the left hand side. See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269298/if-sin-x-sin2-x-1-then-find-the-value-of-cos8-x-2-cos6-x-cos4/2269552#2269552, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166927/if-sin-a-sin2-a-1-and-a-cos12-ab-cos8-ac-cos6-a-1-0/2166936#2166936 and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269077/express-sin8-theta-sin6-theta-sin4-theta-sin2-theta-2-as-a-single-term/2269744#2269744

Comment: @Hanno, I meant: Not sure why this is called "Reverse Engineering"  I think  this to be natural derivation of the equality without actually knowing the left hand side.

Comment: Ok., thanks. I should have put the term into quotes right away—as you did ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From the given condition: $\tan x=\frac{1-\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}=\cos 2x.$

Thus:

$$2\cos^6x-2\cos^4x+\cos^2x=\cos^2 x(2\cos^2x(\cos^2x-1)+1)=$$
$$\cos^2x(-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 2x+1)=\frac 12\cos^2x(\cos^2 2x+1)\stackrel{substitute}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cos^2x\cdot(\tan^2x+1)=\frac 12.$$